# What are those u characters that appear when I use NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm a relatively new guy fiddling around with NLTK but I've experience in NLP with other platforms.  I'm wondering what those u' characters that appear when I print lists from the samples.

```
>>> fdist1
FreqDist({u',': 18713, u'the': 13721, u'.': 6862,...
```

What are those u' characters for in each dictionary? Are those indicators of unicode or something?

Comment: They indicate you have Unicode strings.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type